# Writing french character in binary file using c++ / qt

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization, binaryfiles

I have a binary file read/write module in c++ . Which works fine for English language, but fails to read write french character set. What changes do i need to make ? any special encoding type needs to be specified ? (I have access to c++ std libs and qt 4.7 lib functions) .

Comment: What issues do you have? How are your french accentuated characters encoded? Do you use UT8 or IsoLatin1? You should use UTF8. What did you try? Show us some code....

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
QString::fromUtf8(yourString)
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, make sure that your data files are UTF8 and that you open them as UTF8. Make sure that your source code files are UTF8, too, especially if you use any explicit strings in them, but it's better to avoid using explicit strings.